# Black screen with nvidia-driver-455 - but only for specific kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

Today, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 for dual boot with Windows 10.

My downloaded version of Ubuntu apparently came with kernel **5.4.0-42-generic** (I got this from running `uname -r` in the terminal). At first boot I ran software update and this seemingly installed kernel **5.4.0-58-generic**.

I also selected and installed a graphics driver for my GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER. `ubuntu-drivers devices` told me that `nvidia-driver-455` is recommended, so I installed that.

Restarting, I got all the way to the login screen and entered my password. Then the screen turned black. I restarted and this time I selected **5.4.0-42-generic** in the boot manager (instead of **5.4.0-58-generic** which the boot now defaulted to). Now, I got past the login screen.

Any ideas why the screen turns black with the latest update? Will the driver not work with the **5.4.0-58-generic kernel**?

I tried going back to the default driver (`xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`) but with that driver I don't even get to the login-screen. Instead, it seems like the boot-up crashes and shows a black screen with a lot of unreadable text.

**UPDATE 1**:

Following the comment from @doug, I tried this:

1. Booted in the 5.4.0-42-generic kernel
2. Selected the X.Org X server from the GUI in Ubuntu
3. Removed the nvidia drivers with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
4. Reboot into the 5.4.0-58-generic kernel
5. Installed the nvidia driver using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455`
6. Reboot into the 5.4.0-58-generic kernel

Screen still goes black after login.

**UPDATE 2**:

I decided to re-install Ubuntu (deleting the partition used for Ubuntu, creating a new partition and running the installer again) and this time I made sure to reboot in-between updating the kernel and installing the driver:

1. Update the kernel
2. Reboot
3. Install nvidia-455 driver
4. Reboot

This has the same result, however: The screen goes black after login.

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia driver? If you installed it using a `.run` file, it is an expected behavior.

Comment: When you updated/upgraded the kernel you should have rebooted before installing nvidia driver. Or you should have installed the driver before the kernel upgrade.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't use a `.run` file. I used the graphical tool in Ubuntu and selected the driver from a set of checkboxes.

Comment: @doug Does this mean I should reinstall everything or is there a way out?

Comment: Try reinstalling the nvidia driver or completely removing it, rebooting into latest kernel and reinstalling driver. Completely removing is a little bit of a chore because it is now installed via a ton of packages.

Comment: @doug I tried removing and reinstalling the nvidia driver but screen still goes black after login. See my update in the description above. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. I'm using the 450 driver & see no issue with that kernel. What does this show? `ls /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/`

Comment: @doug It gives me `455.38  kernel-5.4.0-58-generic-x86_64`

Comment: @doug as you can see from my latest update, the problem persists after re-install and making sure to reboot after kernel update. Any other suggestions?